# phonegap-nfc on iOS opens the Ready To Scan under the app

Tags: ios, cordova, nfc, phonegap

I'm using the [phonegap-nfc](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) plugin and I have a button in my app which is simply calling the following function

```
function iosNFC(){
    nfc.beginSession(
        function(){console.log("Success");},
        function(){console.log("ERROR");}
   );
}
```

The problem is the iOS "Ready to scan" box doesn't pop up over the app like it does in [this vide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuP7eWAboC4) instead its there under(?) it. The only way I know its worked at all is if I double click the home button to switch apps and then "Ready to scan" takes dialogue box takes focus and works as expected.

I have  NFC Tag Reading capability in my Xcode project so now I'm wondering is this an iOS issue or a phonegap problem?

Comment: in NFC have not showing any box.. it's default functionality ..when you need to add box you may to create box using nslayer..

Comment: I don't think I can do that from the Phonegap Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the issue was with PhoneGap (version 7.0.1 and iOS PhoneGap Version 4.4.0). I rebuilt the app using Cordova and everything worked as expected.

See the issue and resolution at https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/issues/283